# Чтение переменной реестра с типом reg_binary

Tags: java, реестр

Как считать значение переменной реестра типа reg_binary? К примеру значение переменной типа reg_sz читаю кодом ниже. Но при попытке обратиться к типу reg_binary получаю null.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = com.sun.deploy.util.WinRegistry.getString(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\\Desktop", "TranscodedImageCache");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не могу подсказать насчет WinRegistry, но, когда мне нужно было залезть в реестр, я делал это через виндовую команду "reg query". Правда, она не умеет выводить только значение параметра, поэтому придется распарсить вывод:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("reg query \"HKCU\\Control Panel\\Desktop\" /v TranscodedImageCache");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (line.startsWith("TranscodedImageCache")) {
        String value = line.split("\\s+")[2];
        System.out.println(value);
        break;
    }
}
```